# Get an item to bounce in a 2D, top-down, world

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my 2D, top-down (with an angle), world. When I chop trees, mine nodes, kills enemies, etc. Items spawn in the world; logs, ores, weapons, etc.

I've been trying for a few days to get them to behave like this picture when they spawn (appear in the world):

[image]

I.e taking a random direction, and "bouncing", while slowing down and eventually stopping.
I've experimentet a lot with `AddForce` using `Impulse` together with `gravity` on my `RigidBody2D` that I then set to 0 in script when it should stop. But I cannot get the effect I want.

So say I had a method called `SpawnItem()` that is called on `Start()` that adds this movement to my item, probably only for 0.5-1 seconds. How could I achieve this? If it's impossible to get it in all (random) directions, then just left or right would do fine.

All I can find on this subject involves side-scrollers where you can easily just bounce it off a collider. But in a top-down you can't do that.

EDIT: Here is a video showing the (almost) exact behaviour I want: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LxvYHsEJi9U

Comment: Your description sounds like you have a 3D world with a fixed camera (which is not the same as a 2D world)

Comment: Hmm, then I suck at describing. Its a normal 2D, top-down world with an orthographic camera. Like the old zelda/pokemon games for gameboy. Please let me know if I can change/add anything to make it more clear.

Comment: Your graphic of the bounce is NOT top down as in the ground is NOT purpendicular to the camera. It's 2.5D which is different.

Comment: Didn't know 2,5D was a thing, then your right its NOT 2D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way could be creating an animation for the game object you want to spawn that will simply be it's sprite moving up and down and when you spawn your game object just push it towards the direction you want while playing the animation.

Here's a good article on getting a cool top-down bouncing effect:

https://yal.cc/top-down-bouncing-loot-effects/

Comment: Cool, didnt even think of that, thanks! Looks like what I need :)

Comment: Running into an Issue. When I create an animation in Unity using the Animator, in order to simulate a "bounce" I need to change its position on the y-axis. If I do this, this causes the item to always spawn at the coordinates stored in the Animation, and not from the object they should "come out" from

Comment: I tried messing around with root position, but when I use that it just doesnt move at all anymore.

Comment: Don't use root position, just move it via code. Also you should animate a CHILD of an object you want to move, otherwise the position you set via code will be overriden by animation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know will you see my comment after a long time.

i found some codes and i improved the code so here is the my full script:

trnsObject = trnsBody, what you drag to trnsObject, drag the same object to trnsBody

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class BounceDue : MonoBehaviour
{
public UnityEvent onGroundHitEvent;
public Transform trnsObject;
public Transform trnsBody;
public float gravity = -10;
public Vector2 groundVelocity;
public float verticalVelocity;
private float lastVerticalVelocity;
public bool isGrounded;
private float randomYDrop;
float firstYPos;

private void Awake()
{
 

}
void Start()
{
    randomYDrop = Random.Range(-1f, 1f);
    firstYPos = transform.position.y;
    Set(Vector3.right * Random.Range(-1, 2) * Random.Range(1f, 3f), Random.Range(2f, 5f)); 
}

void Update()
{
    UPosition();
    CheckGroundHit();
}
public void Set(Vector2 groundVelocity, float verticalVelocity)
{
    isGrounded = false;
    this.groundVelocity = groundVelocity;
    this.verticalVelocity = verticalVelocity;
    lastVerticalVelocity = verticalVelocity;
  
}
public void UPosition()
{
    if (!isGrounded)
    {
        verticalVelocity += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        trnsBody.position += new Vector3(0, verticalVelocity, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    trnsObject.position += (Vector3)groundVelocity * Time.deltaTime;

}
void CheckGroundHit()
{
    if (trnsBody.position.y < firstYPos- randomYDrop && !isGrounded)
    {
        trnsBody.position = new Vector2(trnsObject.position.x, firstYPos - randomYDrop);
        isGrounded = true;
        GroundHit();
    }
}
void GroundHit()
{
    onGroundHitEvent.Invoke();
}
public void Bounce(float division)
{
    Set(groundVelocity, lastVerticalVelocity / division);
}
public void SlowDownVelocity(float division)
{
    groundVelocity = groundVelocity / division;
}
```

}

[And look at the script settings for onGroundEvent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw4bk.png)